# Переключение выделения строк таблицы кнопками вверх / вниз

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, table

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реализовал выделение таким образом:

```
$('.focus').click(function(){ // Вылавливаю нажатие
        $('#layer').fadeIn('fast'); // Затеняю фон фрейма
        $(this).closest('tr').each(function(){ // Получаю id строки
            $(this).find('td').each(function(i){ // Нумерую ячейки строки
                $(this).addClass('num'+i+'');
        })}); 
        $('.num0,.num1,.num2').addClass('marked'); // Присваиваю стиль к ячейкам
        $('body').css('background-color', 'white'); // Для правильного затенения общего фона
        $('body', parent.document).css('background', 'rgba(0,0,0,.5)'); // Затеняю index.php
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - $(window).height()/2.3}, 1500); // Прокрутка до центра
    });

    $('#layer').click(function(){  // Отменяю стили, возвращаю всё в зад
        $(this).fadeOut('fast');
        $('.num0,.num1,.num2').removeAttr('class');
        $('body').css('background-color', 'rgba(255,255,255,.0)');
        $('body', parent.document).css('background', 'rgba(0,0,0,.0)');
    });
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать переключение стиля между строками вверх / вниз кнопками на клавиатуре?

Набросал заготовку, но на нажатие почему то реагирует только со второго раза. Это ладно, как мне прикрутить переключение между соседними строками?

```
    $(document).on("keydown", function(e){
//  e.preventDefault();
    if(e.keyCode == 38) {
        // up
     alert('up');
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 40) {
        // down
     alert('down');       
    }        
    });
```

Думал сбрасывать стили и снова применять с инкрементом / декрементом id, но таблица заполняется из базы и естественно, ни о какой порядковой нумерации не может быть и речи. Может как то можно динамически вылавливать id соседних строк?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете попробовать примерно так: https://codepen.io/malginovdesign/pen/LYYYmrm

```js
$("table").on("click", "td", function(e) {
  $("table").addClass("active");
  $("table tr.clicked").removeClass("clicked");
  $(e.target)
    .closest("tr")
    .addClass("clicked");
});
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 38: // up
      changeRow("up");
      break;

    case 40: // down
      changeRow("down");
      break;

    default:
      return; // exit this handler for other keys
  }
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});

function changeRow(dir) {
  var currentRow = $("table tr.clicked");
  var nextRow;
  if (dir == "up" && !currentRow.is(":first-child")) {
    nextRow = currentRow.prev();
  } else if (dir == "down" && !currentRow.is(":last-child")) {
    nextRow = currentRow.next();
  }
  nextRow.addClass("clicked");
  currentRow.removeClass("clicked");
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.active {
  background: grey
}

td {
  padding: 8px
}

.clicked {
  background: white
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  padding: 8px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Адаптировал Ваш код под свой проект, всё получилось! Спасибо!

Comment: Нет проверки на существование блока, в ином случае будет вываливаться эксепшн: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined.

Comment: @MoloF Да, всё верно. Ошибку видно через отладку. Не подскажете ли, как можно организовать такую проверку на существование предыдущего и следующего блока ?

Comment: @Incognito , необходимо добавить строчку перед добавлением класса nextRow - if(nextRow === undefined) return;

Comment: @MoloF Спасибо, помогло!